# passing props to child item and overriding some

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to React Native and i'm trying to create a TextInput that I can style based on the focus state of the textInput.
My understanding is that subclassing is not big in react, so i'm trying the approach of creating a component containing the text input.

So I created this component:

```
class FocusTextInput extends React.Component<{}, { isFocused: boolean }> {
  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isFocused: false };
  }
  onFocus() {
    this.setState({ isFocused: true });
  }

  onBlur() {
    this.setState({ isFocused: false });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        {...this.props}
        // style={this.state.isFocused ? { backgroundColor: 'red' } : { backgroundColor: 'green' }}
        style={{ backgroundColor: '#aaa' }} // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<  If i delete this line then it works, just no style override
      />
    );
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to use it like so:

```
      <FocusTextInput
        ref="digit0"
        isFocused="false"
        onChangeText={this.handleDigitChanged.bind(this, 0)}
        style={styles.digitFramedControlDigit}
        maxLength={1}
        returnKeyType="next"
        selectTextOnFocus
        selectionColor="#ffffff00"
      />
```

So i'm able to pass those properties to the child (TextInput), how can i override the style though?

Also, i'm not sure that this is the right approach as if I want to call any of hte methods exposed by InputText on my FocusTextInput, I have to declare those methods and forward the method call. That seems silly.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most recommended way is to use an array syntax to override from parent:

In child (**FocusTextInput**), apply: `style={[{ backgroundColor: '#aaa' }, this.props.style]}`

It's read from left to right. So `backgroundColor` is by default *#aaa*. And if `this.props.style` has new definition for it, then it'll override the previous one(s).

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding !important to you styling. See below.

```
 style={{ backgroundColor: '#aaa !important' }}
```